# Using the POST method with Sequelize

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm trying to debug a situation where I can't seem to create a new record for my object based on the values the user inputs into the form fields. Right now I'm getting hung up on the object creation aspect where the post isn't recognizing the `.create`. Should I be also be using `.create` or `.build`? I tried both and the same error occurred.

```
TypeError: Ann.create is not a function
    at /Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/nodeapp/app/controllers/appRoutes.js:13:20
```

appRoutes.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var appRoutes   = express.Router();
var Annotation = require('../models/annotation-model');

appRoutes.route('/') 

    .get(function(req, res){
        res.render('pages/activity-feed.hbs');
    })

    .post(function(req, res){

        var annotation = new Annotation.create({

            annotation_date: req.body.annotation-date,

        }).then(function(user){
            console.log(user.get({plain:true}))
        });



        annotation.save(function(err){
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
        });
    });

module.exports = appRoutes;
```

Controller index (dbIndex.js):

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize('test', 'admin', 'pwd', {
    host:'localhost',
    port:'3306',
    dialect: 'mysql'
});

sequelize
        .authenticate()
        .then(function(err) {
            if (!!err) {
                console.log('Unable to connect to the database:', err)
            } else {
                console.log('Connection has been established successfully.')
            }
        });

var db = {}

db.Annotation = sequelize.import(__dirname + "/annotation-model");

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

annotation-model.js:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

var Annotation = sequelize.define('table', {
    annotation_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    annotation_date: DataTypes.DATE,
}, {
    freezeTableName: true
});
    return Annotation;
}
```

form for POST method (activity-feed.hbs):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" style="background-color:#ffe680;">
        <div class="annotation-form">
            <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="Generic placeholder image">
            <form action="/app" method="post">
                <label for="annotation-date">Annotation Date:</label>
                <br />
                <button>Create</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: `req.body.annotation-date` should be `req.body['annotation-date']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two parts to the solution to this issue. Both parts are found within the `appRoutes.js` file.

1. `var models` should point to the `dbIndex.js` file and not where the model is defined (`annotation-model.js`). `var models = require('../models/dbIndex);`
2. You must specify the object within the `dbIndex` so that we can use the `.create` method. This means `models.Annotation.create()`

Answer (score 0):

Reason why you get `Ann.create is not a function` because you didn't have proper reference to your `annotation-model.js:` if you follow this structure https://stackoverflow.com/a/33981210/880709 everything will be ok, see `models/index.js` and `routes/index.js` plus read [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/1.7.0/articles/express/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I agree that your answer will work, but I don't want to have to restructure so many filed and the documentation you are referring to is outdated. Posting an answer that worked.

Comment: current sequelize documentation is outdated?

Comment: You are pointing to the `1.7.0` version. Sequelize is now in version `3.14.2` based on the github changelog